# My components are not visible on the JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm  a new java programmer and I'm facing this problem. The JButton and textfield i added are not showing on my panel. I really don't know why since I've already added all the components to the panel

Here is my code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class aboutUs extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton b,b2,b3,b4;
     JTextField t1;
     JTextArea a1;
     JPanel p1, p2,p3,p11,AboutPanel;
     JFrame about = new JFrame ("About us");
     JRadioButton r1,r2;
     JMenuBar menu;
     JMenu open;
     JMenuItem aboutFrame;

     public aboutUs (){

        about.setSize(500,500);

        about.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        about.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        about.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        about.setResizable(false);
        AboutPanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (1,2));
        t1 = new JTextField (30);
        AboutPanel.add(t1);
        b4 = new JButton ("click here");
        AboutPanel.add(b4);
        add(AboutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        about.setVisible (true);
     }

     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

     }
}
     class test {

     public static void main (String [] args){
        aboutUs a = new aboutUs();
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a `JFrame` called `about` and making that visible.  But the `aboutUs` class is a `JFrame` and you have added the button and text to that.

Change:

```
add(AboutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

to

```
about.add(AboutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

add `about.pack()` and then `about.setVisible (true);`

edit: and yes like Steve said you are missing also `about.add(AboutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
about.add(AboutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```